# Drawn string (using drawString) flickers

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm doing this project here, and I have to draw a string to prevent me some problems, the drawing works and the string updates just fine, thing is, it tends to flicker somehow. It's like it's being redrawn, and while it's acceptable to think that it needs to be redrawn due to how the values change, I'm pretty sure that it's not that idea that I can it 'flicker' as it is drawn once more.

Here's the code concerning the drawing of the string:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    g.drawString("Arca: " + administrador.getCiudad().getArca() 
    + "                                    " 
    + " Puntos de Belleza: " + administrador.getCiudad().getPuntosBelleza() + 
    "                                    " + 
    " Habitantes: " + 
    administrador.getCiudad().getCantidadHabitantes() + " / " 
    + administrador.getCiudad().getCantidadHabitantesDisponibles(), 400, 45);

    repaint();
}
```

If you need any more information just tell me and I'll give it to you!

Comment: BTW - instead of overriding `paint()`, consider adding a `JTextArea` or a `JTable` or..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
repaint();
```

Don't invoke repaint() from a painting method. You will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much, I did not know paint() worked like that! -- as soon as the website lets me accept your answer I'll do so!

Comment: (Possibly) also overriding `paint` of a top level container

Comment: but there's this issue, as I remove repaint(), the String will no longer update. You see, the variables within the string are updated every second and therefore I need the string to display the changed values!

Comment: Based on your code posted we can't help you here because we have no idea what the rest of your code looks like. But in general in you want something continually updated then you should probably use a Swing Timer to schedule the updates. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Then in the ActionListener for your Timer you would invoke repaint() on the component.

Comment: Just tried to place a timer inside the paint function, but it's not exactly working out.

Comment: *'Just tried to place a timer"* For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  As a *new* question.

Comment: The paint() method is only for painting. The Timer is started somewhere else in you program. As I said earlier I can't give you any more advice. Read the tutorial. Download and run the example. Search the forum for other examples.